# XSLT foreach

Tags: xslt

Hi i have a strange issue with matching specific attribute of xml node.
Example code that doesnt work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="../../unit/service/price/season[@name=$period_name]">
     <xsl:attribute name="std_bed_price">
          <xsl:value-of select="../@amount"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Example code that DOES work but i don't like this way too much:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="../../unit/service/price/season">
     <xsl:if test="@name = $period_name">
          <xsl:attribute name="std_bed_price">
               <xsl:value-of select="../@amount"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

If in first example i replace the variable name with some of the values like 'A' it works, 
i also tested what variable name is selected and it has the correct data inside (so, 'A','B','C' ...)

Anyone had this problem before?

Tnx

Comment: Please post the XML snippet that produces the described behavior for you.

Comment: What language and framework are you using for XSLT, or is this being done in a browser?

Comment: How is the $period_name variable set?

Comment: This is an example how *not* to ask a question. The XML and the XSLT transformation are not provided. How can one even understand the question not to say try to find the problem? Not surprizingly there are no useful answers: we are not clairevoyants!

Please edit or delete + reformulate + resubmit

Answer (score 3):

You might try changing it to an apply-templates instead of a foreach. Something like the following should work.

```
<xsl:template match="price">
    <xsl:attribute name="std_bed_price">
        <xsl:value-of select="@amount" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

And then call it like:

```
<xsl:apply-template select="../../unit/service/price/[season/@name=$period_name]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not seen this before. Could it be an ambiguous @name attribute. Therefore try accessing it like below?

```
select="../../unit/service/price/season[./@name=$period_name]
```

Other than that, sorry, to me it looks like it should work perfectly both ways.